# AttributeError: 'MappingKernelManager' object has no attribute 'connect_control'

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I recently upgraded my Anaconda 3 environment from 2019.03 to 2019.07 and started having problems connecting to jupyter notebook kernel which was running fine. I am running Windows 10 1903, and problem is the same with Edge and Chrome browsers (Version 76.0.3809.100)

I open Anaconda prompt, write "Jupyter notebook", connect to the provided URL from browser ok. After this when I attempt to open an existing notebook or create a new one, I get the first box but have a sign on top left stating "connecting to kernel" and nothing happens (I cant run the python content). Command prompt states the following:

```
[W 18:39:19.693 NotebookApp] Replacing stale connection: 52cdf5d1-ecc7-4eb6-be3e-5f2721563f71:1cb0e9060a9043cf81d90bcdc66e92df
[I 18:39:45.715 NotebookApp] Starting buffering for 52cdf5d1-ecc7-4eb6-be3e-5f2721563f71:1cb0e9060a9043cf81d90bcdc66e92df
[I 18:39:50.589 NotebookApp] Creating new notebook in
[W 18:39:50.890 NotebookApp] 404 GET /static/components/react/react-dom.production.min.js (::1) 15.63ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Untitled8.ipynb?kernel_name=python3
[I 18:39:51.332 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 1593c869-7614-4652-8a2a-c146de11d100
[I 18:39:52.517 NotebookApp] Adapting from protocol version 5.1 (kernel 1593c869-7614-4652-8a2a-c146de11d100) to 5.3 (client).
[E 18:39:52.526 NotebookApp] Uncaught exception GET /api/kernels/1593c869-7614-4652-8a2a-c146de11d100/channels?session_id=35ad854ba53946b583300b9953a75cbf (::1)
    HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8888', method='GET', uri='/api/kernels/1593c869-7614-4652-8a2a-c146de11d100/channels?session_id=35ad854ba53946b583300b9953a75cbf', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='::1')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\MuratCudiErentürk\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tornado\websocket.py", line 956, in _accept_connection
        open_result = handler.open(*handler.open_args, **handler.open_kwargs)
      File "C:\tools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\handlers.py", line 274, in open
        self.create_stream()
      File "C:\tools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\handlers.py", line 127, in create_stream
        meth = getattr(km, 'connect_' + channel)
    AttributeError: 'MappingKernelManager' object has no attribute 'connect_control'
[W 18:39:53.550 NotebookApp] Replacing stale connection: 1593c869-7614-4652-8a2a-c146de11d100:35ad854ba53946b583300b9953a75cbf
[I 18:41:51.338 NotebookApp] Saving file at /Untitled8.ipynb
```

Answer (score 3):

I was hitting this same error with jupyter-client==5.2.4 and jupyter-core==4.4.0. I then upgraded to jupyter-client==5.3.1 and jupyter-core==4.5.0 and it went away. You may try upgrading these two packages to see if it fixes the issue.

I'm not on Anaconda on this system but I think this should work:

```
conda update jupyter-client jupyter-core
```

If not, you may try:

```
pip install --upgrade jupyter-client jupyter-core
```